# Pick multiple index of a specific list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, random, minesweeper

Greetings to whoever reading this!
I have been assigned to make a minesweeper program in python where yeah I could just copy paste an already made one but I wanted to make it myself but I'm having a hard time with my lists here.
To make things a little bit more clear I have the main list lets call it List within it I have 10 more lists for the rows of the games board BUT
now that I have to add the mines to it I can't find a way to randomly place them around the lists!

```
x=random.choice(list)
    board.replace(x,"nuke",forrow)
-----------------------------------------
x=randrange(len(list))
    board.replace(x,"nuke",forrow)
--------------------------------------
x=random.sample(list[i],1)
    board.insert(x,"nuke")
----------------------------------------
    for x in range(len(list)):
            board.insert(random.choice(x),"nuke")

import random
board = [[" "]*10 for i in range(10)]# here i create the big list and the other ones within it

bombs=15#input("Please provide the amount of bombs you want in the game: ")

for list in board: #here is my problem
    x=random.sample(list[i],1) 
    board.insert(x,"nuke")



for x in board:print x
```

I am expecting anything that is able to help me out on my little program 
I need something to be able to get the position of X amount of positions in a list and be able to replace them with a "bomb" so call it!

Comment: Don't use list as variable name. Also what are you expecting from this line? `x = random.sample(list_[i], 1)`

Comment: With `random.sample` (or `random.choice`) you are getting an element from the list, not a random index. Try `randrange` instead. Also, `insert` will _add_ a "nuke" instead of changing one cell to a nuke.

Comment: list_=['a','b','c','d'] what i want is to get from list_ 2 randoms f.e. 'b' ,'d' but not them i want there position list_[1] list_[2] and when i get there location replace them with something else (i hope i helped you :/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of randomly picking positions in the field, how about this approach: Initialize a long list with the right amount of "nukes" and empty cells, `random.shuffle` that list, and break it down to a 2D-board.

```
>>> bombs = 15
>>> all_cells = ["nuke"] * bombs + [" "] * (100 - bombs)
>>> random.shuffle(all_cells)
>>> board = [all_cells[i:i+10] for i in range(0, 100, 10)]
```

This way, you do not have to check whether you already randomly rolled the same cell before.